# how to convert pdf to xml file

Tags: ios, xml, database, pdf, format

I have downloaded a book online in pdf format and want to use the book in my ios project. The required format is in xml. The format is like:

```
<q>question here</q>
<a>answer here</a>
<q>question2</q>
<a>answer2</a>
```

the pdf format is like:

```
               the question is centered
    the answer has several paragraphs that start with 4 white space. 

    This is another paragraph
               This is the second question and so on

    This is the answer to the second question

               The third question and there may be a blank line above
    This is the 4th question and no blank line above
```

I have tried using word/pages to convert the pdf to txt and read the text line by line, but I am not able to identify the questions and answers. Another problem is when I do the conversion, the auto wrappings of pdf are converted to line breaks.

Note: The process is

```
pdf -> use word/pages -> txt -> python program -> xml -> python program -> sqlite database
```

The critical part is how to convert the pdf into the correct xml file.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, you can find a usable, open source and friendly pdf viewer from github.com or somewhere else. then you can parse the converted text and generate xml.